# Is the YouTube API is Free or Paid?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am a little confused with regard to the YouTube api.  It stats [Quote cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) and I Wanted to check Is the YouTube API is Free or Paid?

Because when i checked it is showing some dollars amount for an every API calls.

Comment: IIRC, you get some number of free calls per day, after which it starts becoming billable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen do you have a link to where this is documented, I have never heard of the YouTube API "becoming billable" after you have reached your quota allotment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of Googles APIs are free to use, but you are given a small quota limit. You can then request additional quota at a later date if you need more.   Depending upon how much you ask for you may be charged for the additional quota.

This is not something i have ever heard of with regard to the YouTube api.  I suspect your confusion is related to the fact that the YouTube API is cost based.   However the cost is not in money the cost is in points against your quota allotment.    Say you have 10000 quota points to use for the api, and you make a request against videos.list the cost of this request is 1 quota points. that means you now have 9999 quota points remaining.  While video.insert costs 1600.

Its not a cost in money its a cost in quota points. I have a video that may help you understand this a bit better. [YouTube API and cost based quota demystified](https://youtu.be/MHUGuw1Agnc)

You may also want to review the [Quota cost calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) which will give you an idea of how many points each request costs.

Comment: Thank you @DalmTo for the information and the link, In the Quota Calculator I see the cost per calls or set of calls, what if I want to download any of my compitators video analytics details, how to do it. Is there any Free software or tools which helps to fetch the YT data for free.

Comment: Sorry i cant help you with software for that,  I dont think its actually allowed by YouTube TOS its not part of the API.